# Fourier transform of convolution in a finite range

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution

Can anyone help me evaluate the Fourier transform of of the following function,
$t \in \mathbb{R}$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,

$f(t) = \int_{t_0}^t e^{-\lambda(\tau - t)} g(\tau) d\tau$, for $t \geq t_0$.

This equation shows up in the state-space solution of a second-order linear initial value ODE. I'm trying to consolidate the state-space solution with one found using Fourier / Laplace transforms.

I have found a number of identities of Fourier transforms applied to infinite range convolutions. I'm not sure how or if they apply here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One approach: stick a rect function $\left(r(\tau)=1 \text{ for } t_0<\tau<t \text{ and 0 otherwise } \right)$  inside the integral and then extend the limits to $\pm\infty$ . You'd then probably end up taking an FT of the exponential term multiplied by the rect function which would itself become a convolution of a sinc function and a Lorentzian function (which I *think* is doable as an integral...not tried it). You might prefer to attach the rect function to $g$ depending on what it was...

Comment: Actually thinking about it, said integral involving rect function and exponential will become trivial; probably best explained in an answer. I'll try and put it together..